# Making a div appear on scroll

Tags: javascript

I am looking to make a header appear after you scroll down (Immediately after).

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Jsfiddle (Doesn't look right but whatever): http://jsfiddle.net/3b6P4/

Can someone insert the javascript needed to put a header div fixed to the top that shows up when scrolled? Thanks

Comment: 'jquery header scroll top' on Google.

Comment: Hello Tyler, welcome to SO :)

Comment: ^Thanks, been lurking till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="appear">
<h1>Cool</h1>
</div>

<style>
#appear{display: none;}
</style>

<script>
function appear()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('appear');
    div.style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', appear, false);
</script>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/3b6P4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Updated your jsfiddle example aswell:

http://jsfiddle.net/3b6P4/1/

```
console.log(
   // accompanied code
);
```